# PayPal Express not redirecting back to Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have entered API Username, Password and Signature from PayPal and added 'tokenParam' => 'craftToken' in Craft config and yet when I try to make a payment using PayPal Express I get the following....

https://www.site.com/index.php/actions/commerce/payments/completePayment?commerceTransactionId=114&commerceTransactionHash=0ec5451ed35b360311214dfa75aee88f&token=EC-9GX1527947961953D&PayerID=RFN3LXKUP6SVQ

With the following error:  The requested URL was not found on this server.

Any suggestions on what I have missed.

Here is my `craft/config/general.php` file.

```
$domain = 'www.site.com';

if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
    header("Location: https://" . $domain . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); exit(); 
}

define('URI_SCHEME',  ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) ? "https://" : "http://" );
define('SITE_URL',    URI_SCHEME . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/');
define('BASEPATH',    realpath(CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/../') . '/');

return array(
    '*' => array(
            'siteUrl' => SITE_URL,
            'environmentVariables' => array(
            'siteUrl'  => SITE_URL,
            'basePath' => BASEPATH,
            'defaultImageQuality' => 60,
            'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
            'tokenParam' => 't',
        ),
    ),
);
```

FORM

```
{% if cart.paymentMethodId %}

    <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="paymentForm">

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/payments/pay"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/shop/customer/order?number={number}"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="/shop/checkout/payment"/>

        {{ getCsrfInput() }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the output in your templates of:

```
{{ craft.config.tokenParam }}
```

If it isn't `t` suspect your config is not setting the tokenParam for some reason.

Can you test with a stripped out general.php with only hard-coded values (No multi-environment config, or `if($_SERVER ...` checks)

```
return array(
    'tokenParam' => 'myCraftToken'
    // ..other hard coded settings
);
```

Comment: Bingo.  Thank you Luke.  Using {{ craft.config.tokenParam }} we were able to narrow it down.  Server security issue on our end.  Commerce worked perfectly.  Awesome product.

Answer (score 1):

Things I can think of to check:

Are you using test mode, or is this live (and have you got that set correctly in Commerce's settings?).  If live, test mode needs to be `false`.

Also, do you have the appropriate action, redirect for complete payments and cancelled ones set in your form?

```
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/payments/pay">
 <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/cart/complete?number={{ cart.number }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="/cart/payment">
```

Also, try disabling CSRF on your site for your testing - does that make a difference?

When do you get that url/error - is that when it's re-directing to Paypal, or when it is coming back?

Comment: Hello Jeremy,
I am not in test mode.  I checked that as well as the actions in the form.  It is giving me the error when it is coming back from PayPal.

Comment: Did you try disabling CSRF as a test?

Comment: Also where you say `https://www.site.com` - you've manually changed that here, right?  That's not the actual url you're getting back (in which case it would be your site url being wrong I guess?)

Comment: Hey Jeremy.  I replaced my site name with that.

Comment: Hey Brad, yes I tried disabling CSRF.  I bought another license for Commerce today for another site.  It is doing the exact same thing.  It was straight out of the box.  So whatever I am doing (or not doing) I am being consistent.  With this second there is nothing I changed from the original code.

Comment: Can you post your form code, just for extra checking

Comment: <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" id="paymentForm">
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/payments/pay"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/shop/customer/order?number={number}"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="/shop/checkout/payment"/>
     {{ getCsrfInput() }}

Comment: After reading the docs another 60 times it seems as though the tokenparam setting is not taking effect.  I added it to the craft config file.  Whatever I am missing it is doing it on two commerce sites I am trying to develop.  This is the first two commerce sites I have done.  Everything was simple until I got to this step.

Comment: Can you edit the original question to share your `craft/config/general.php` file where you're setting the `tokenParam` config setting?